# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, pdf

In my Angular app, I have installed via `npm` the `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer` so that I can display the content of pdf files.

As per instructions, I have included the following in my `angular.json` file:

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
    "output": "/assets/"
  }
],
  "scripts": [
    "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js",
    "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/viewer.js",
    "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.worker.js"
],
```

However, when I build my app using `ng build`, I get this error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Script file node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js does not exist.
```

There seems to be only [one](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/614/757786179) post on the www that mentions this message, and I don't really understand that...

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Where did you find the outdated documentation? I'd like to update it. Be that as it may, this copy of the documentation is up-to-date: https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/getting-started

Comment: @StephanRauh I found it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/v/1.8.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, installing ngx-extended-pdf-viewer has become a lot simpler. You don't need the `scripts` section. The `pdf*.js` files are loaded automatically. Your advantage: you benefit from lazy loading, and your PDF viewer is a lot faster.

Technical deep dive: Many users of my library had problems with caching. When I publish a new version, they'd still use the old version of pdf.js. To solve this problem, I've added the version number to the file names. That, in turn, causes your error message.

Not including the JavaScript files has two other advantages. First, the pdf*.js files are only loaded when needed. So your initial bundle is a lot smaller, and the application loads faster. Second, `pdf.worker.js` is executed in a worker thread. For large PDF files that's a factor ten performance boost.

Comment: I get http 404 not found for 
http://localhost:4200/assets/op-chaining-support.js and 
http://localhost:4200/assets/pdf-3.10.557-es5.min.js

Comment: Create a new green-field Angular project and add ngx-extended-pdf-viewer. This takes roughly 10 minutes and rewards you with a running application. After that, compare the `angular.json` of your broken project and your green-field project. Usually, this helps you to find and fix the problem quickly. Here's the instruction how to get ngx-extended-pdf-viewer up and running: https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/getting-started